# Increasing the size of a f:field (input) with Grails Fields Plugin (but without loosing DRY)

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I want to change this:

[image: 1]

By this:

[image: 2]

Twitter Bootstrap make it easy. We just have to add: `class="input-xxlarge"`. But if we just add this to a f:field, it doesn't work:

```
<f:field bean="bestInstance" property="honor" class="input-xxlarge"/>
```

The solution so far is to copy the source code generated with the f:field and add it. This is the result code (after adding `class="input-xxlarge`):

```
<f:field bean="bestInstance" property="honor">
    <input class="input-xxlarge" type="text" name="direccion" value="" required="" maxlength="100" id="direccion" />
</f:field>
```

It works, but it is not DRY anymore. Is there any way to do it without loosing the DRY capacity of Grails Fields Plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `input-class` instead of `class`. Read [documentation](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html), section: **Default Behaviour - Using Grails Input Tags**